# Duplicate listen options error

Tags: nginx

I'm getting the following error when checking for syntax errors by running `sudo nginx -t`.

```
nginx: [emerg] duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default~:4
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

What could be causing duplicate listen options? It says the error is on line 4 of my nginx default file. I've included the first 6 lines of the file below. I haven't found any other questions with this specific error and I'm so new to nginx I don't know where to start looking for a solution to the problem.

```
# HTTP - redirect all requests to HTTPS:
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

I'm following a tutorial on Digital Ocean the full default file contents can be [seen here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04#configure-nginx-for-https).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a temporary file named `default~` created by emacs in the same directory that was causing the problem. **Simply remove the temp file and the error should go away.**